# Plugin class doesn't exist

Tags: magento-2.1, error

I tired to delete an extension and now getting:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Plugin class Aheadworks\OneStepCheckout\Plugin\App\FrontController\CoreBridgeInitializer doesn't exist
```

Deleted the files from `/code` directory
Deleted associated databases.
Deleted module from `setup_module` table.
Deleted module entry from `app/etc/config.php` file.

Still this error is showing...

Comment: I'd suggest to text-search all your theme and /app/code/ folders for "CoreBridgeInitializer". Something must be calling this class which "doesn't exist"

Comment: See what I propose.
Try to clear your Magento cache and system cache (where available)
If you still have the same problem, try to find some third-party extension or custom which generate the link to extension plugin. Hope, I could help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try following commands:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
// -f to use in default and developer mode
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean

//To run command forcefully
php -f bin/magento <your command>

//To run command with memory limit 4G
php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento <your command>

//To run command with max memory limit
php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento <your command>
```

Comment: Any help same error https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/320473/57334 thanks @Pratik Oza

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem again and the solution from @PatrickOza did not work for me.

*Plugin class doesn't exist error was occurring when trying to add a product.*

I found that the module I was trying to remove, added *attributes* to the `eav_attribute` table.

I did a search with a wild card (Like %...%) on `source_model` column that contains anything related to the module and removed those rows. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

For those who might be having a similar problem. I was getting this error:

```
Plugin class Magezon\Core\Plugin\View\Element\AbstractBlock doesn't exist
```

Turns out the issue was due to the "case" of the containing folder.

In /app/code I had created a folder called "magezon" - it needed to be "Magezon" with a capital M.

Hope this helps someone down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Check your registration file as the name might be incorrect.

```
Magezon\Core\registration.php
```