# Fresh Magento - admin menu is not working

Tags: admin, javascript, backend, magento2.2.2

Buttons on left admin menu does not react on mouse actions.

The error in console says

> ***TypeError: Formatter is not a constructor***

I tried

```
setup:static-content:deploy
```

but nothing happens.

Comment: Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/209309) link.

Comment: Try to change your environment, let's say developer to production and check if problem is solved

Comment: magento2.2 not support setup:static-content:deploy instead of you need to use
setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: @Jeremy, what console errors do you get? Would be worth if you added it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Windows os?

If yes then may be issue related symlink file,

please follow the below steps to fix the same…

1)Remove everything, except .htaccess file from pub/static folder

2)Open up app/etc/di.xml find the path 
      “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink” 
 and replace to 
      “Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy”

Note: Remove entire files and folder under pub/static except .htaccess file.

after run

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

or  for old magento2 version

```
 php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

i got same issue that time i was follow bellow

[link](http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/)

.

```
 http://www.dckap.com/blog/magento-2-admin-links-not-working-in-windows/
```

Answer (score 1):

Error shows because of magento admin not able to get the js files values.

**Possible Solutions 1 :**

> **1)  go to app/etc/di.xml find the line**
>
> **Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink**
>
> **and Replace it with**
>
> **Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy**

**Possible Solutions 2 :**

> **2) Goto Magento 2 root directory -> pub -> static and remove static**
> **folder and remove var/cache, var/composer_home, var/generation,**
> **var/page_cache, var/view_preprocessed**
>
> **After that run below commands**
>
> - **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
> - **php bin/magento cache:clean**
> - **php bin/magento cache:flush**

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands ans check

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so based on the description I see the following as possible solutions.

1. You have broken generated code. In Magento 2.2.* the `generation` folder under `var` does not exist anymore, it has been moved to root folder of the installation under the folder `generated`. Clear the contents of that folder.
2. You don't have a record for `dev/static/sign` in the `core_config_data` table and if you do it's set to 1 instead of 0. If you don't use the MySQL query below.

You haven't provided much information can't assumed anything else.

```
INSERT INTO 'core_config_data' ('path', 'value') 
VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

3. You haven't cleared your browser cache.