# I am getting an error when i run setup:di:compile

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am **getting an error** when i run the command `setup:di:compile`.

[image]

Even my `requirejs-config` file 2 is not getting deployed.

Can any one help me with this

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/209293/plugin-class-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following command.

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento cache:flush
- php bin/magento cache:clean

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with one of your module class **Vendor\MyModule\Plugin\Customer\LoginPost**, debug or disable that module and then clear / delete your following folder and deploy your code again :

to disable module :

- php bin/magento module:disable Vendor_ModuleName

Then clear ( delete following ) your module :

- generated/code
- pub/static/frontend/
- pub/static/adminhtml
- var/view_processed/pub

and then run all magento commands to upgrade / compile and deployment :

- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f