# Magento 2 - Install extension using composer error - Plugin class Searchanise\SearchAutocomplete\Plugins\Toolbar doesn't exist

Tags: composer, magento2.3.4

After install extension using composer, extension installed successfully but not visible on back-end how to solve this issue.

Screenshot :

1. extension : https://marketplace.magento.com/searchanise-search-autocomplete.html
2. Install cmd : **composer require searchanise/search-autocomplete:1.0.10**
3. module installed : https://snipboard.io/xOQR3i.jpg
4. Run proper commands
5. Not visible on back-end https://snipboard.io/tRUph5.jpg

How to solve the issue.

Log Error : [2020-08-22 06:49:36] main.ERROR: Plugin class Searchanise\SearchAutocomplete\Plugins\Toolbar doesn't exist [] []

Answer (score 0):

Remove extension and reinstall using the following steps:

```
composer require searchanise/search-autocomplete
```

Run following command after package installed:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

> FYI there is no file in vendor/ but still, i am facing an error
> already defined in
> '/var/www/html/giri/vendor/searchanise/search-autocomplete'.

Because you've installed **Searchanise** extension via composer and after you've installed by copying a package from store.
In this case, it conflicts vendor module. Now we can resolve this issue in 3 simple steps:

**Step 1:** You should DELETE module from

```
app/code/Searchanise/SearchAutocomplete
vendor/searchanise/search-autocomplete (if any)
```

Run the following command:

```
composer remove searchanise/search-autocomplete
rm -rf app/code/Searchanise/SearchAutocomplete
rm -rf vendor/searchanise/search-autocomplete
composer dump-autoload
```

**Step 2:** Now install Searchanise_SearchAutocomplete again run upgrade command line to resolve the issue.

```
composer require searchanise/search-autocomplete
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**Step 3:** Check result

Comment: After removed extension using composer remove, then i manually import extension after i am getting following error https://snipboard.io/KupP5b.jpg

Comment: FYI there is no file in vendor/ but still, i am facing an error  already defined in '/var/www/html/giri/vendor/searchanise/search-autocomplete'.

Comment: Check above updated answer.